# How to make all LOVs auto submit by default in Oracle ADF

Tags: java, oracle-adf

We have deployed a huge system built on ADF, and now we want to make some edits on specific components like LOVs.

We want to make all LOVs in the application AutoSubmit by default. Of course some sort of scripts can do the job but we are actually seeking to keep it default so in case we needed to add these components later.

Answer (score 0):

If possible avoid autosubmit in every LOVs, some components may behave differently than what is expected, you should only apply autosubmit="true" wherever is required.
If you really want to do this, follow the steps below:

- In Jdeveloper open your project
- goto search -> find in files..
- search for these keywords one by one : input, select
- Apply file types filter to only .jsff
- go through all search result and insert property autoSubmit="true".

The reason i have mentioned input, select keyword is all those components start from input or select ex: inputText, selectOneChoice, selectOneCheckbox, inputDate, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Lalji Gajera but Actually i was looking for a way to keep default settings of LOVs AutoSubmit = true not just change the value of current LOVs .. and of course we'll consider your opinion about keeping autosubmit limited as possible.